# How to write Index, Match matrix in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a matrix in excel that works fine:

```
=INDEX('KIT e SVLAN'!N:N;MATCH(1;('KIT e SVLAN'!A:A=E3)*('KIT e SVLAN'!AK:AK="S")*('KIT e SVLAN'!AL:AL="AT");0))
```

i'd like to add to it another condition: ('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L="0")

to get something like:

```
=INDEX('KIT e SVLAN'!N:N;MATCH(1;(('KIT e SVLAN'!A:A=E4)*('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L="0")*('KIT e SVLAN'!AK:AK="S")*('KIT e SVLAN'!AL:AL="AT"));0))
```

when i press Ctrl+Shift+Enter the second matrix gives N/A where actually it must return a value. What could be a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Using entire column references within an array formula is a disastrous idea. Your second formula is being forced to calculate more than 4 million cells, an absolutely astonishing amount for a single formula.

Comment: which could be a solution? VBA or alternative formula?

Comment: Have you verified that there is at least one row for which all those conditions are met? That is the only way I can why you are getting #N/A as a result, i.e. there are no rows matching all 4 conditions.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `...*('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L=0)*...` but that would also allow blank cells. You should also add a non-blank condition like `...*('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L=0)*SIGN(LEN('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L))*...`. Additionally, pay heed to the warning by @XORLX on full column references in array formulas. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum.

Comment: @XOR LX yes, there are a lot of rows to which this conditions match.

Comment: @Jeeped Good spot. I didn't notice the OP was using "0" instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, the formula with mentioned by You syntax works perfectly.I know that it's not optimal to use a whole column as a reference, but i use it as far updating file 1 per day the number of rows changes, so instead updating formula with a new last row each time, i used the whole column

Comment: If you provided enough details about your data, a suggested formula for a dynamic **named range** could be suggested. This could be referenced by the array formula such that only **exactly* as many rows as needed are referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the quotes from the `...*('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L=0)*...` section, you have a working formula as,

```
=INDEX('KIT e SVLAN'!N:N;MATCH(1;(('KIT e SVLAN'!A:A=E4)*('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L=0)*SIGN(LEN('KIT e SVLAN'!L:L))*('KIT e SVLAN'!AK:AK="S")*('KIT e SVLAN'!AL:AL="AT"));0))
```

To make it more efficient, change the referenced data block on the **KIT e SVLAN** worksheet to a dynamic named range. By referencing the named range, only **exactly** as many rows will be processed as is needed. The range will reshape itself as new rows are added or removed.

One of the static conditions for the formula is that column AL be equal to `"AT"`. If we cut down the range to the last row containing any text in column AL, nothing below that matters as they would never be returned in any event. The last row containing a text value in column AL can be arrived at with the following formula,

```
=match(char(255); AL:AL)
```

Yes, there is a quoted space being matched. The space is important for the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to return the last row from a column of text.

Your columns seem to have specific purposes so I am going to assume that you have text based column header labels along the top row.

Go to Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager. When the Name Manager dialog opens, click <kbd>New</kbd>.

1. Give the range a name. I've chosen **kesDATA**.
2. Leave the *Scope:* as **Workbook**. Optionally provide a comment.
3. Provide the following formula for the *Refers to:*,
    
         `='KIT e SVLAN'!$A$1:index('KIT e SVLAN'!$A:$XFD; match(char(255); $AL:$AL); match(char(255); $1:$1))`
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to create the name then <kbd>Close</kbd> to close the dialog.
5. [optional] Test the new named range by tapping <kbd>F5</kbd>, typing **kesDATA** and clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>. You should select the entire named range.

   [image: Name Manager - Create New Name]
                      <sup>Name Manager - Create New Name</sup>

Now change your formula to one of these array formulas¹,

```
'for zeroes and blanks in column L
=INDEX(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 14); MATCH(1; (INDEX(kesDATA; ; 1)=E3)*NOT(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 12))*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 37)="S")*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 38)="AT"); 0))
'for zeroes in column L but not blanks,
=INDEX(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 14); MATCH(1; (INDEX(kesDATA; ; 1)=E3)*NOT(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 12))*SIGN(LEN(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 12)))*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 37)="S")*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 38)="AT"); 0))
```

... or one of these standard formulas using the newer [AGGREGATE² function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to accomplish the multiple column criteria processing.

```
'for zeroes and blanks in column L,
=INDEX(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 14); AGGREGATE(15; 6; ROW(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 14))/((INDEX(kesDATA; ; 1)=E3)*NOT(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 12))*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 37)="S")*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 38)="AT")); 1))
'for zeroes in column L but not blanks,
=INDEX(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 14); AGGREGATE(15; 6; ROW(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 14))/((INDEX(kesDATA; ; 1)=E3)*NOT(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 12))*SIGN(LEN(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 12)))*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 37)="S")*(INDEX(kesDATA; ; 38)="AT")); 1))
```

Those formulas might look complicated but they will require a small fraction of the calculation cycles that your previous array formulas¹ did.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

² <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Your construction for finding the last non-empty row from a column of text entries is interesting, though perhaps not the most rigorous. Not all text strings are >" ". A single hyphen ("-"), for example, is not, and so would potentially cause your construction to fail. Of course, you might argue that the list of characters which cause your construction to fail comprises only those which are so obscure or so rare as to occur in any practical situation that its being only 99.9% rigorous should nevertheless be sufficient. However, personally I feel we should always strive for 100% :-)

Comment: @XORLX - Typically, I've used `match("zzz", $AT:$AT)` in the past. The one above is something new I'm trying out.

Comment: I suppose you could offer it with the caveat that it may not work if any non-alphabetic strings are present, though that's perhaps not ideal, especially given that the "zzz" approach is guaranteed to work with all strings including special characters. Also, just as with the "zzz" approach, I've noticed that your new attempt may fail if there are any null strings ("") within the range, so that's another caveat!

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for Your detailed explanation. But the first thing i see is that =match(" "; AL:AL; -1) does not find the last row as far AL column values are "AT", "OR" or Blanks.

Comment: @Jeeped I haven't mentioned numeric data at all in my assessment of your new construction.

Comment: @Ale When you say "Blanks", do you mean "genuine" blanks or the null string "", e.g. as a result of formulas in those cells?

Comment: @Ale - Columns of numeric data would require `match(1e99, A:A)`. The trick for a dynamic named range is to pick one column that you know what the data will look like and choose the right formula for that column. Any column will do as the number of columns is determined by the column header labels; you are only looking for the total number of rows in this case. In a block of data, there is usually at least one column that is always filled with either a number, date or text.

Comment: @XOR LX no, the column AL values are not formulas, blanks values have the length = 0

Comment: @Ale If the only entries in column AL are either "AT", "OR" or else "genuine" blanks then I don't see how Jeeped's construction for finding the last non-empty row in that column can fail. That said, it's in general not the most rigorous construction (although it may be sufficient for your set-up), so you may wish to see here for some others: http://superuser.com/questions/982343/make-an-array-formula-in-excel-calculate-only-on-active-rows/982611#982611

Comment: fwiw, i have modified the 'last text row' formula above.

Comment: @Jeeped is not it possible to take another column, that does not contain any blanks? For example, ='KIT e SVLAN'!$A$2:INDEX('KIT e SVLAN'!$2:$1048576;MATCH(" ";'KIT e SVLAN'!$E:$E; -1);MATCH(" ";'KIT e SVLAN'!$1:$1; -1)) as kesData works smoothly

Comment: @ale - Yes. That was my point. That was also why I asked you above in the original question's comments for some sample data. You can pick any column to determine the number of rows; if it is numbers or dates then use `match(1e99, $A:$A)` and if it is text use `match(char(255), $A:$A)` where `$A:$A` is the column you choose.